# How can i add indexing in mysql view table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
CREATE VIEW test AS SELECT
wp_posts.ID,
wp_posts.post_title,
STR_TO_DATE(pm1.meta_value,'%c/%e/%Y') AS expiration_date,
pm2.meta_value AS ceadmin_email,
pm3.meta_value AS student_email,
pm4.meta_value AS email,
pm5.meta_value AS cefirst_name,
pm6.meta_value AS celast_name
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm1 ON (wp_posts.ID=pm1.post_id AND pm1.meta_key='ceexpiration_date')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm2 ON (wp_posts.ID=pm2.post_id AND pm2.meta_key='ceadmin_email')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm3 ON (wp_posts.ID=pm3.post_id AND pm3.meta_key='secondary_email')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm4 ON (wp_posts.ID=pm4.post_id AND pm4.meta_key='email')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm5 ON (wp_posts.ID=pm5.post_id AND pm5.meta_key='cefirst_name')
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS pm6 ON (wp_posts.ID=pm6.post_id AND pm6.meta_key='celast_name')
WHERE wp_posts.constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'
AND wp_posts.table_schema=DATABASE()
AND wp_posts.table_name='owalog'; wp_posts.post_type='student_certificates' AND pm2.meta_value IN (SELECT user_email FROM supervisorcount)
```

Comment: [EAV](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav), [Antipatterns](http://www.sheeri.org/sql-antipatterns-bill-karwin/) and the horrible queries they create. Thank you Wordpress. Is customary to ask a question associated with a SQL query too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-restrictions.html) on views:

> It is not possible to create an index on a view.

So, you really have two options available here:

- You may tune the query underlying the view, by adding appropriate indices on the actual tables involved, or
- You may create a temporary table using the query behind the view, and then index that directly.

MySQL does not have any formal materialized view, but a temporary table comes pretty close to this.  Note that in general a (non materialized) view will perform only as well as the underlying query.

Comment: Is there Any another way to speed up fetch data from view my Query take
(Query took 107.6422 seconds.)

Comment: Other than what I wrote above, no, I don't know of a way.  Maybe you could write your query with fewer joins/logic.